# Install a third-party OS image using NOOBS?

Tags: operating-systems, noobs, bootloader

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and RaspBMC installed using NOOBS, but I was wondering if it is possible to install a third-party OS, that is not included with NOOBS, using NOOBS?

I was considering trying to install Pi MusicBox, but I don't want to use a separate SD card and I like the multiple OS feature in NOOBS. I was thinking that extracting the OS image into the /os folder on the Pi's SD card might work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is definetly possible to install other operating systems, but why would you want to do it via NOOBS?

Comment: @Bex I like being able to easily choose the OS I want to boot, rather than having to change the SD card. Also, I already have Raspbian and RaspBMC installed using NOOBS, so it's easier to use NOOBS than a different bootloader like BerryBoot.